# Blender 2.91.2 zooming out from an object until it disappears but will not come back when zooming in

Tags: depth-of-field

Just loaded Blender 2.91.2 and the object in question is a small table (size x 240mm, y 150mm, z 230mm) and clip start settings are 0.001mm and clip end settings 100000mm.

Furthermore, if I zoom out until the object is just before the vanishing point (but I can still see its presence) zooming in doesn't work.

I don't know if this is a bug with this version or perhaps I have some settings wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: select the object and press numpad period.